# How to assign Tab Pages dynamically and add a single text box to store the data from text box into the database using c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So I am creating forms using Visual Studio .NET.

I am stuck when I try to add tab pages dynamically on a button click which creates a text box in a new tab.

When I create multiple tabs I want to get the data from the text boxes of each newly created tabs and add it to the database. I am having problems as these text boxes have the same name as I create them dynamically. I am new to C# and I need help.

```
 public void add()
        {
            aa.Add(txt.Text);

            var a = 1;
            var newTabPage = new TabPage()

            {
                Text = "Page" 
            };

            txt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.tabControl1.TabPages.Add(newTabPage);
            newTabPage.Controls.Add(this.txt);

            System.Windows.Forms.Label lbl = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            newTabPage.Controls.Add(lbl);
            lbl.Text = "New";
            txt.Name = "Get";



            lbl.AutoSize = true;
            lbl.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            lbl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 389);
            lbl.Name = "label263";
            lbl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(871, 13);
            lbl.TabIndex = 317;
            lbl.Text = "AA";

newTabPage.Controls.Add(lbl);
        }
        private void txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)


        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            add();

            string value = txt.Text;


            aa.Add(value);
           }

private void saveToolStripMenuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand command; 


           string insert1 = @"insert into testing(test) values(@testingt)";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();


                    for(int i= 0;i<aa.Count;i++)
                    {

                        if (aa[i]!= ""  && aa[i]!="New Box")
                        {
                            command = new SqlCommand(insert1, conn);

                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"testingt", aa[i]);
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
}
catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can set the Name property to distinguish them when you create them by creating an increment variable.

```
int pagecount = 1;
private void btAddtab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TabPage tabPage = new TabPage
    {
        Name = "Tabpage" + pagecount.ToString(),
        Text = "Tabpage" + pagecount.ToString()
    };
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox
    {
        Name = "TextBox" + pagecount.ToString()
    };
    tabPage.Controls.Add(textBox);
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
    pagecount++;
}
```

As for how to get the value of the specified TextBox, you can refer to the following code.

```
private void btGetValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TabPage page in tabControl1.TabPages)
    {
        foreach (Control control in page.Controls)
        {
            // get the first textbox's value
            if (control is TextBox && control.Name == "TextBox1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(((TextBox)control).Text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```